# How can I get the position of the tracked picture when detected in Unity with AR foundation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am using unity AR foundation image tracking. When a tracked picture appears on the screen, how can I get its position or its relative distance to the camera?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the distance from the camera to the picture by giving the camera position and the game object transform position of the identified picture. I'm currently using this in one of my apps and its working nicely.

```
Vector3.Distance(pictureGameObject.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position)
```

Answer (score -1):

well you would need the position of that other object to check the Distance. This can be done by using `Vector3.Distance`.

First however you need the `Transform` of the other object. You can do this by making a Raycast, in this case I'm casting the raycast from the middle of the screen. Then I will assign the `Transform` of whatever object was hit to the `hitTransform` variable. After that I can use a `Vector3.Distance` to compare 2 positions and calculate the distance.

```
Transform hitTransform;
private float distance;

void Update()
{
    Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 0));
    RaycastHit hit

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        hitTransform = hit.transform;
    }

    distance = Vector3.Distance(hitTransform.position, transform.position);
}
```

So in short, if you look at an object that is in the middle of the screen the distance between that object and the camera will be in the `distance` variable, you can also use a raycast when you click or press a button but for the sake of simplicity I used the middle of the screen for this.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that you're not guaranteeing that the image they're raycasting at is the Tracked Image - Which is likely one of the issues the question asker has

Comment: @KieranBond this is true however from what i read there is 1(?) image. in that case i guess this would work.